Is there any need for me to write a conditional to check for a leap year?
I'm currently taking the cs50p course on edx, and I'm stuck on the problem set 8 "Seasons of Love". We were supposed to write code that calculates the amount of years a person has lived in minutes. But my code doesn't pass all the given tests. I'm thinking if it has to do with the year I'm currently in: for example if I input a date from like a year ago today, their code returns 525600 minutes but mine returns 570400.
from datetime import date
import sys
import operator
import inflect

p = inflect.engine()

def main():
    date = input("Date of birth: ")
    print(validate(date))


def validate(d):
    try:
        birth = date.fromisoformat(d)
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit("Invalid Format")

    today = date.today()
    difference = operator.__sub__(today,birth)
    time = difference.days * 24 * 60
    output = p.number_to_words(time)
    return f"{output.capitalize()} minutes"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Does this answer your question? How to determine whether a year is a leap year?

difference = operator.__sub__(today,birth) is a very weird way to write difference = today - birth.

Don't use operator.__sub__ at all; operator.sub is the preferred version (when any such function is appropriate) since Python 3.7. (Both have been available since at least Python 1.5, so __sub__ is retained for backwards compatibility.)

You already have timedelta object - have it do all the heavy lifting with total_seconds, and then divide by 60 to get the value in minutes:
time = difference.total_seconds() / 60

